# Merge / append / concatenate two QueryBuilders?

Tags: rust, sqlx

I have many `sqlx::QueryBuilder`, can I merge them together?

Example:

```rust
let first: QueryBuilder<'a, sqlx::Postgres> = QueryBuilder::new(r"1 ");

let mut third = QueryBuilder::new(" 3");

first.push(" 2");

first.append(third) // append() doesn't exists

assert_eq!(first.sql(), "1 2 3");
```

Is this possible today somewhat?

Comment: The purpose of `QueryBuilder` is to build valid SQL queries. This does not look like a valid SQL query, so I'm not sure what your goal is. This seems a lot like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me. What is your actual goal here, and can you illustrate it with real code instead of sample code?